# PhpStorm header.php file is greyed out

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm and for some reason in all of my projects the `header.php` file got messed up. It's just greyed out and PhpStorm doesn't recognize the PHP in the specific files named `header.php`. The rest is working fine.

[image]

It's driving me crazy and I can't figure it out. I already checked file templates, reset it to default. Nothing helps.

I would appreciate any solution, thanks.

Comment: Probably a broken *file type association*. Somehow you've configured a special type association for files named "header.php" in your settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Locate `Text` entry in top table
3. Locate and remove `header.php` (or very similar one) pattern from bottom table and remove it.

Right now you have somehow told IDE to treat such file as Plain text and it does it for all files named `header.php` regardless of their location (quite likely it happened when you were creating new `header` file and forgot to enter `.php` part).